# Finding the appropriate ABI to read input data

Tags: tokens, etherscan, nodejs, abi

Given the transaction hash
`0x7da7a1645278c94434bdc8f54eae8f8f6bf8d1a730d84af38ffcc05ded24492f`

I would like to understand the input data better.

To do this, I attempted loading the ABI of the verified smart contract listed on Polygonscan here
`0xf715beb51ec8f63317d66f491e37e7bb048fcc2d`

This is obtained via the **getABI** endpoint provided.

I then use that ABI to decode the input data from the **eth_getTransactionByHash** endpoint, using abi-decoder.

Unfortunately, each attempt at decoding has returned *undefined* . I have tried different inputs and ABIs, but feel I might not be understanding this concept completely. Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

**Code:**

```js
let resp = await axios.get(`https://api.polygonscan.com/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=${tx_hash}&apikey=${this.apiKey}`);

if (resp != null && resp.statusText == 'OK'){
    const contract_address = resp.data.result.to;
    let abi_res = await axios.get(`https://api.polygonscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${contract_address}&apikey=${this.apiKey}`);
   if (abi_res != null){
     if(abi_res.statusText == 'OK'){
        var abi = abi_res.data.result
        const abiArray = JSON.parse(abi);
        abiDecoder.addABI(abi);
        // console.log(abiDecoder.getABIs());
        // console.log(resp.data.result.input);
        const decodedMethod = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(resp.data.result.input);
        console.log(decodedMethod)
      } else{console.log(abi.statusText)}
    } 
}
```

[****Link on PolygonScan****](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7da7a1645278c94434bdc8f54eae8f8f6bf8d1a730d84af38ffcc05ded24492f)

Comment: It seems to be an abi-decoder limitation with some ABIEncoderV2 types.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the transaction data of a transaction by using a library like [Ethers](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/).

First, get the ABI from PolygonScan:

```typescript
const contract_address = "0xf715beb51ec8f63317d66f491e37e7bb048fcc2d";

const abi_res = await axios.get(
  `https://api.polygonscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${contract_address}`
);

const abi = JSON.parse(abi_res.data.result);
```

Then fetch the transaction data. You could use the PolygonScan API here, but a more solid approach is using Ethers with a public RPC url.

```typescript
const  provider  =  new  providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://polygon-rpc.com");

const transaction = await provider.getTransaction(
    "0x7da7a1645278c94434bdc8f54eae8f8f6bf8d1a730d84af38ffcc05ded24492f"
);
```

And then, using Ethers and the ABI, we can decode the data:

```typescript
const inter = new utils.Interface(abi);

const decoded = inter.parseTransaction({
  data: transaction.data,
  value: 0,
});

console.log(decoded);
```

In this case, it seems to be a `matchOrders` with 6 arguments.

```json
{
  "args": [
    ...
  ],
  "name": "matchOrders",
  "signature": "matchOrders((address,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,bytes,bytes,bytes,bytes),(address,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,bytes,bytes,bytes,bytes),bytes,bytes,(address,uint256)[],address)",
  "sighash": "0xbbbfa60c",
  "value": { "type": "BigNumber", "hex": "0x00" }
}
```

Check out the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-abi-and-decode-transaction-623hif?file=/src/index.ts).

You can use online tools for decoding transaction data like [this](https://www.turfemon.com/tools/transaction-data-decoder), or [this](https://www.moesif.com/solidity-abi-hex-decoder/decode).